# Loading large mysql select statements into python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have two mysql databases called database `A` and database `B`. I want to use python to copy all the data from a table in database `A` to a table in database `B`. The datatable holds approximately 5M rows. I have written the following code:

```
connection = make_connection(source_db)
c = connection.cursor()
batch_size = 100000
while True:
    batch = c.fetchmany(batch_size)
    print('Extracted a batch.')
    if not batch:
        break
    insert_data(batch)

connection.close()
```

I ran this code and it takes minutes for `fetchmany()` to extract a single batch. I've tried to use `fetchall()` without the `while True` statement but this takes even longer.

**Question:** How do I successfully speed up this process/what is the best way to load large select statements into python?